# Lists in local function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this function that works fine. But I am not quite sure how it works

Here is the code:

```
def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-1]
    return sorted (strings, key=last_letter)
```

execution:

```
sort_by_last_letter(['hello','python','programming'])
```

It returns the result fine but I don't understand how the local function `last_letter` automatically breaks up the list of strings. Is it the `sorted` function that sends one string at a time for sorting?

Comment: As an aside, the local function could be dispensed with and `return sorted(strings, key=itemgetter(-1))` used instead. Along with `from operator import itemgetter`

Comment: If you added a `print(s[-1])` in the function it would become clear

Comment: It looks like `sorted key` argument gets the last element of the string and then sorts the results. Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it works is as follows:

When you `return sorted(strings, key=last_letter)` gets executed, it will sort `strings` based on the `key=last_letter`, so `sorted` method will pass each element from `strings` to `last_letter` which will return last char of the passed element (string). So the sorting will be based on the last char. of each string of the `strings` list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .. Cheers :P

Answer (score 3):

`sorted` takes a list and we are passing an optional parameter `key` to control how the comparison between the items would be performed. The function passed to the `key` argument is called with each item in the list and the function returns a value. The returned values from each call are then used as the basis of comparison.

Here, we are using the `last_letter` function as the `key`. Each of the list item is passed to the `last_letter` function. The function returns the last letter from the sting. Then the `sorted` function sorts based on those values, that is the last letter of every item.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the string like `s[-1]` it is used as a char array. So `s[-1]` returns the last letter of the string. It is then used in the `sorted` function as the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

Your `key` function sorts the list according the values returned by each item of the passed list like so:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+
| hello | python | programming | # each item in the list you passed into the sort function
+-------+--------+-------------+
|   o   |    n   |      g      | # the resultant value of your key function on these items
+-------+--------+-------------+
```